# Victorian Love Letter - The name has rubbed off. Who do you deliver it to?

Tags: riddle

A presence almost feline seems to follow wherever you go, such is your grace. The brilliance of thy concentrat'd beauty would pierce a steel aegis as sure as my heart, though through you the beauty of company kept only increaseth. Fiercer than the sword of Uriel, your shine is to mine eyes more potent than the heavens. Though thou hast deigned to speed arrows to me, a wound is a creature that can be left banish'd by your touch.

Belt me not as I ascend to your bedchamber and kiss your cool lips, for my adulation deluxe is beyond control.

**Name the intended recipient of the letter with your reasoning behind it.**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The recipient is

> a laser pointer

A presence almost feline seems to follow wherever you go, such is your grace.

> cats love to chase the dot from the laser

The brilliance of thy concentrat'd beauty would pierce a steel aegis as sure as my heart,

> The laser is a concentrated beam of light, and some types can be used to cut through material

though through you the beauty of company kept only increaseth.

> cosmetic lasers*

Fiercer than the sword of Uriel, your shine is to mine eyes more potent than the heavens.

> looking into a laser can easily damage eyes

Though thou hast deigned to speed arrows to me,

> laser sights on weapons

a wound is a creature that can be left banish'd by your touch.

> laser surgery

Belt me not as I ascend to your bedchamber and kiss your cool lips, for my adulation deluxe is beyond control.

> adulation de luxe -> lover of light*

*Missing explanations provided by OP

Comment: How about "belt me not"?

Comment: @AE Cats like batting the laser. Belting and batting are synonyms of hitting.

Comment: That part is flavor rather than substance. I'm still not sure that that last bit was well written.

Answer (score 6):

The intended recipient is:

> Spirit (strong distilled alcoholic drink)

written by:

> Alcoholic

**Reasoning:**

> "feline" could be interpreted as: 
> *"sly, stealthy, or treacherous"*
> rather than,
> *"belonging or pertaining to the cat family"*
> according to [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/feline).
>
> The alcoholic loves the presence and feeling of alcohol which he describes as grace. He feels her treacherous presence everywhere he goes, because he is the one seeking after her (unintentionally).
>
> "Concentrat'd beauty" also speaks of spirit (as in strong concentrated alcohol).
>
>
> He speaks of piercing with arrows and the ferocity of a sword -> the effect of alcohol, which however can be banished, once they meet again! :D
> (besides as [Geobits](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1563/geobits) points out: *Alcohol is/was often used as a sterilization method for wounds*)
>
> He also describes what her shininess does to his eyes -> the shiny look of the spirit in the bottle (especially after a few...).
>
> That is why he wants to go into her bedchamber even this night and kiss her once again... kiss her cool lips (bottle/glass lips)... emphasizing he's got no control over his situation! :D

It reminds me very much of the Bible proverb:

> **[Proverbs 23:30-35](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs23%3A30-36&version=ESV)** (ESV)
> Those who tarry long over wine;
>     those who go to try mixed wine.
>  Do not look at wine when it is red,
>    when it sparkles in the cup
>     and goes down smoothly.
>  In the end it bites like a serpent
>     and stings like an adder.
>  Your eyes will see strange things,
>     and your heart utter perverse things.
>  You will be like one who lies down in the midst of the sea,
>     like one who lies on the top of a mast.
>  “They struck me,” you will say, “but I was not hurt;
>     they beat me, but I did not feel it.
>  When shall I awake?
>     I must have another drink.”

Comment: "*...through you the beauty of company kept only increaseth.*" -> beer goggles

Comment: Presence almost feline?

Comment: Well reasoned, but incorrect. It only fits about half of the criterion.

Comment: Also, "*...a wound is a creature that can be left banish'd by your touch*": Alcohol is/was often used as a sterilization method for wounds.

Comment: @TravisKindred nevertheless it was a pleasure trying to give it such a meaning. However I am kind of glad this is actually not the answer as that would be quite sad... xD

Comment: If I wrote a Victorian style love letter to booze, it wouldn't feel like a challenge. I've already written so many.

Comment: Related: ["Rose" by The Feeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrk1PBtt3QY)